# How to split rows within a dataframe for a target column with multiple/nested values

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

With a dataframe that has, for example, one column x that has nested or multiple values for some rows, how would i, for those rows that have multiple values for x, append duplicate rows to the dataframe, save that that they correspond to one value within x.

To try to explain better, see "mock dataframe pre-transform", below. Row 1 has values "webui, cli, mobile" for column "module",  and what i want is to append three near copies of row 1 to the dataframe, one with module value "webui", one with module value "cli" and one with module value "mobile". I also then want to remove the the original row 1. A similar operation would occur for row 4, such that the final dataframe would have 7 rows (see "mock dataframe post-transform, below).

[mock dataframe pre-transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbSPV.png)

[mock dataframe post-transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiDJU.png)

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/10/data-pivoting-with-tidyr/

Comment: I would go in a loop over the unique values of column ID or reference. 

select the rows for each value, consider the column x, split y,z into two and form a column and do cbind with the unique value and append to a empty data.frame.

Comment: I think this is a little too theoretical. Can you please provide a sample dataset? It doesn't have to be real data, or big. Clear corner cases are important here. For instance, if in row `n`, one column has `"x,y"` and another column (same row) has `"X,Y,Z"`, what do you think should happen? (Anything other than the equivalent of `expand.grid(c("x","y"), c("X","Y","Z"))` is a problem.)

Comment: edit: i have made my example clearer, with mocked dataframe images.

Comment: do some more investigation i have solved by using the tidyr package and unnest_longer() on the target column:

new_dataframe <- original_dataframe %>%  unnest_longer(target_column)